# Can't find yes or no button in App content while publishing apps on play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

Can't find Yes/No button, thou I have added all the other information

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wly7a.png

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug which is currently present in the Play Stores UI. Try to open this page with a different browser. On my Mac, it failed with Firefox but worked with Safari.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug in play store console. Your adblocker blocked the radio buttons. Please disable the adblock and refresh the page in order to see the radio buttons